# prefersLargeTitles with a GroupedListStyle SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

I have a parent view where I want to navigation title to be large. Then I push a child view with a grouped table view and I want to navigation title to be `inline`:

This works well with SwiftUI but when my parent is a UIViewController with `prefersLargeTitles = true` and I push a `UIHostingController(rootView: ChildView())` the navigation bar title in the child jumps

Here is the expected behaviour (using SwiftUI only)

[image]

Here is the behaviour when pushing from UIKit:

[image]

This is the SwiftUI code that works

```
struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("SwiftUI")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: navigationButton)
                .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI Parent", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }

    var navigationButton: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
            Text("Push")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let list = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    var body: some View {
        List(list, id: \.self, rowContent: Text.init)
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI Child", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView()
    }
}
```

And the is how I push the SwiftUI child from UIKit

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "UIKit Parent"

        let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Push", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pushChild))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    @objc
    func pushChild(_ sender: Any) {
        let childViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ChildView())
        navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set child view controller's `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never` before pushing it(even it is UIHostingController).

```
func pushChild(_ sender: Any) {
    let childViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ChildView())
    childViewController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController, animated: true)
}
```